# How do I create a Hibernate Criteria query where I have to filter through multiple relations?

Tags: hibernate, entity-relationship, hibernate-criteria

Suppose I have an entity like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ITEMS")
public class Item  {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "item")
    private Set<ItemParameterValue> parameterValues;
}
```

It has a relation with `ItemParameterValues`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ITEM_PARAMETER_VALUES", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"item_id", "parameter_id"}))
    public class ItemParameterValue {
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "parameter_id")
        private ItemParameter parameter;
}
```

which has a relation with `ItemParameter`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ITEM_PARAMETERS", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "sid"))
public class ItemParameter {

}
```

So for example I have some `Item` which has a parameter value of "220" which has a parameter named "Voltage". I have to filter for 220 but the value 220 can belong to many parameters, I need the one which belongs to the parameter "Voltage".

I know I can do something like this (assuming I set up the proper aliases):

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Item.class);
// ...
c.add(Restrictions.conjunction()
    .add(Restrictions.eq("item.parameterValue", "220"))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("item.parameterValue.parameter.sid", "Voltage")));
```

but it seems somewhat cumbersome to me. Is there a more convenient way to handle this kind of relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of createalias you can use createcriteria to shorten it

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Item.class)
    .createCriteria("parameterValues")
        .add(Restrictions.eq("theProperty", "220"))
        .createCriteria("parameter")
            .add(Restrictions.eq("sid", "Voltage"));
```

Comment: Do you have some information about what kind of query Hibernate will generate from this Criteria?

Comment: something along the lines of `SELECT item.* FROM itemtable item join parametervaluetable value on ... join parameter p on ... WHERE value.thevalue = '220' and p.sid = 'Voltage'` note that the collections are not initialised although they are joined because there are filters set and not all children are returned

Answer (score 0):

Creating the appropiate alias, makes the criteria easier:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Item.class);
c.createAlias("parameterValues", "pv");
c.createAlias("pv.parameter", "p");
c.add(Restrictions.eq("pv.theProperty", "220")); // I don't see in your question the name of the property to perform filter
c.add(Restrictions.eq("p.sid", "Voltage"));
```

Additionally, `Restrictions.conjunction()` is not necessary, you aren't grouping AND with ORs  or other complex conditions in this case.